# MySQL error 1062 and 1452 while inserting data into tables

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, mysql-error-1062, mysql-error-1452

Trying to do a course on mysql, following videos and text. From what I thought, I had been following it perfectly, but I am getting a lot of errors when I am trying to insert data into tables.

Here is my code:

```
-- MyExercises

CREATE DATABASE MyExercises;

USE MyExercises;

CREATE TABLE Categories 
        (CategoryID INT NOT NULL, 
        CategoryName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        Description TEXT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CategoryID))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW COLUMNS FROM Categories;   
DESC Categories;   

CREATE TABLE Suppliers 
        (City VARCHAR(20) NULL, 
        CompanyName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        SupplierID INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (SupplierID))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

    CREATE TABLE Products 
        (ProductID INT NOT NULL, 
        ProductName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
        CategoryID INT NULL,
        SupplierID INT NULL,
        UnitPrice DECIMAL(5,2) NULL,
        UnitsInStock SMALLINT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ProductID),
FOREIGN KEY (CategoryID) REFERENCES Categories(CategoryID)) 
ENGINE = INNODB;

INSERT INTO Categories (CategoryID, CategoryName, Description)
VALUES (1, 'Beverages', 'Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales');

INSERT INTO Categories (CategoryID, CategoryName, Description)
VALUES (2, 'Condiments', 'Sweet and savory sauces');

INSERT INTO Categories (CategoryID, CategoryName, Description)
VALUES (3, 'Confections', 'Desserts, candies, and sweet breads');

INSERT INTO Categories (CategoryID, CategoryName, Description)
VALUES (4, 'Dairy Products', 'Cheese, Milk, Cream');

INSERT INTO Suppliers (SupplierID, CompanyName, City)
VALUES (1, 'Exotic Liquids', 'London');

INSERT INTO Suppliers (SupplierID, CompanyName)
VALUES (2, 'New Orleans Cajun Delights');

INSERT INTO Suppliers (SupplierID, CompanyName, City)
VALUES (3, 'Grandma Kelly''s Homestead', 'Adelaide');

INSERT INTO Suppliers (SupplierID, CompanyName)
VALUES (4, 'Tokyo Traders');

INSERT INTO Products (ProductID, ProductName, SupplierID, CategoryID, UnitPrice, UnitsInStock)
VALUES (1, 'Chai', 1, 1, 18, 39);

INSERT INTO Products (ProductID, ProductName, SupplierID, UnitPrice, UnitsInStock)
VALUES (2, 'Chang', 1, 19, 17);

INSERT INTO Products (ProductID, ProductName, CategoryID, UnitPrice, UnitsInStock)
VALUES (3, 'Ani Seed Syrup', 2, 10, 13);

INSERT INTO Products (ProductID, ProductName, SupplierID, CategoryID, UnitPrice)
VALUES (4, 'Chef Anton''s Cajun Seasoning', 2, 2, 22);

INSERT INTO Products (ProductID, ProductName, SupplierID, CategoryID, UnitsInStock)
VALUES (5, 'Chef Anton''s Gumbo Mix', 2, 2, 0);

INSERT INTO Products (ProductID, ProductName, SupplierID, CategoryID)
VALUES (6, 'Grandma''s Boysenberry Spread', 3, 2);

INSERT INTO Products (ProductID, ProductName, SupplierID, CategoryID, UnitPrice, UnitsInStock)
VALUES (7, 'Uncle Bob''s Organic Dried Pears', 5, 4, 30, 15);

INSERT INTO Products (ProductID, ProductName, SupplierID, CategoryID, UnitPrice, UnitsInStock)
VALUES (8, 'Northwood''s Cranberry Sauce', 4, 5, 40, 6);
```

Is there anything that stands out as bleedingly obvious as to why I should be getting errors form inserting data?

Here is where I am getting errors specifically:

[image]
A lot of the errors are things say *Error Code 1062* for duplication, and *Error Code 1452*.

Comment: Empty the tables and try again. There are already those key values in the database. Also consider to set id as auto_increment.

Comment: try lower case version of the tables for a start

Comment: Once you start clean, as suggested above, you'll also need to fix your last `insert` statement's `CategoryID` value to respect the foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You should be issuing your queries one at a time - this way you will see where the error appears.

Error #1062 is probably due to uniqueness of your primary key. Values with ids you are trying to insert already exist in tables. Try truncating entire table and running the script once again.

Error #1452 is probably appearing when trying to insert into `Products` table. This is because you have a foreign key constraint, and previous insert statements issued on `Categories` table failed.

*Note: You don't need to issue insert statements for every row. Instead, you can group them like this:*

```
INSERT INTO Categories (CategoryID, CategoryName, Description)
  VALUES 
    (1, 'Beverages', 'Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales'),
    (2, 'Condiments', 'Sweet and savory sauces'),
    (3, 'Confections', 'Desserts, candies, and sweet breads'),
    (4, 'Dairy Products', 'Cheese, Milk, Cream');
```

You're also missing a foreign key constraint to `Suppliers(SupplierID)` while creating `Products` table, which I guess should exist.

A good advice for you would be to use `AUTO_INCREMENT` for your primary keys that would generate values for you. Check [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) for more information on the subject. This would require you to remove primary key column and values from your insert statements, thus making them shorter and not having to worry about incrementing them every time by hand.

Comment: Thank you for your help here. I wasn't aware that I could add things like that! So what is the best way (simply put please!) to remedy what I have at the moment error-wise?

Comment: Simply put I've included everything in my post. Empty the tables, insert values once again for starters.

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll give it a shot :)